# LibGdx black boxes on top and right where textures don't render

Tags: java, libgdx

I just started to create a Game with LibGdx, but when I render a Texture on the top or on the right side of the Window it won't show on up the Screen. It's like there are two black boxes that are drawn over the texture.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/goVAZ.png)

Here is the code:

```
public class SpaceInvaders extends ApplicationAdapter {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    //MainUI mUI;

    Player p;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        Gdx.graphics.setResizable(false);
        Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(672, 768);
        //mUI = new MainUI(batch);
        p = new Player(batch);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

        // Update
        //mUI.update();
        p.update();

        // Render
        batch.begin();
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 1);

        //mUI.render();
        p.render();

        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

```
public class Player {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture playerImg;
    Sprite sprite;
    //Projectile p;

    public int x = 0, y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 300f;

    public Player(SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
        playerImg = new Texture("res/player.png");
        sprite = new Sprite(playerImg);
    }

    public void update() {
        updateKeys();
        /*
        if(p != null) {
            p.update();
            if(p.y+p.image.getHeight() > Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) {
                p = null;
            }
        }
         */
    }

    private void updateKeys() {
        // D
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(32)) {
            x+=3;
            if(x+playerImg.getWidth() > Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-playerImg.getWidth();
        }
        // A
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(29)) {
            x-=3;
            if(x < 0) x = 0;
        }
        // Space
        /*
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(62)) {
            if(p == null) {
                p =new Projectile(batch, x+playerImg.getWidth()/2-2, y+playerImg.getHeight()+1, 5);
            }
        }
         */
        sprite.setX((float) x);
        sprite.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 300f);
    }

    public void render() {
        sprite.draw(batch);
        /*
        if(p != null) {
            p.render();
        }
         */
    }

}
```

I tried to remove everything except the player but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Definitely you must not clear the screen after already calling `begin()` on the batch. I can't tell from the screen shot what's supposed to be there and what isn't. Your background (clear color) is black, so if you don't see your sprite, it's either black so it blends into the background or not visible at all.

Comment: You absolutely do not want to be designing the game based on Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and getHeight(). This firmly locks you into one specific window size. On 4K monitors, the window will be super tiny and you won't be able to fix it without rewriting every single part of your game code having to do with size or position of anything. You ought to use an ExtendViewport or FixedViewport that manages a camera at the scale you want for your game. Position game world objects based on the viewport size you gave the Viewport instead of the graphics width/height.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and you are right. Im beginner too. The way to fix it is deleting your:

```
Gdx.graphics.setResizable(false);
Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(672, 768);
```

Go to your desktop >src >com.mygdxgame >DesktopLauncher and add this:

```
config.setResizable(false);
config.setWindowedMode(672, 768);
```